# How to use matrix_row::find in boost::numeric::ublas

Tags: c++, boost

i'm trying to use matrix_row.find to check if a number is present in a row of a matrix using boost::numeric::ublas::matrix

- When i use the internal matrix_row.find the result is different from using the std::find.
  This is the code:

```cpp
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#define TABLELEN 9

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
typedef matrix<short> table;

boost::array<short, TABLELEN * TABLELEN> tb_test1_a
{
    0, 6, 0,    3, 0, 0,    8, 0, 4,
    5, 3, 7,    0, 9, 0,    0, 0, 0,
    0, 4, 0,    0, 0, 6,    3, 0, 7,

    0, 9, 0,    0, 5, 1,    2, 3, 8,
    0, 0, 0,    0, 0, 0,    0, 0, 0,
    7, 1, 3,    6, 2, 0,    0, 4, 0,

    3, 0, 6,    4, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0,    0, 6, 0,    5, 2, 3,
    1, 0, 2,    0, 0, 9,    0, 8, 0,
};

// load matrix
void loadMatrix(table &tb, boost::array<short, TABLELEN * TABLELEN> tb_a){
    for(int row = 0; row < TABLELEN; ++row)
        for(int col = 0; col < TABLELEN; ++col)
            tb.at_element(row, col) = tb_a[row * TABLELEN + col];
}

int main(){
    table testtable(TABLELEN, TABLELEN);
    loadMatrix(testtable, tb_test1_a);

    // test find on row 0
    std::cout << "internal boost find"<<std::endl;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){

        matrix_row<table> cc(testtable, 0);
        int V = i;
        std::cout << "row: " << cc << " v: " << V << " found?: ";

        // this is the find in boost
        bool res = cc.find(V) != cc.end();

        std::cout << std::boolalpha << res << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "std::find" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        matrix_row<table> cc(testtable, 0);
        int V = i;
        std::cout << "row: " << cc << " v: " << V << " found?: ";

        // this i the find using c++ std
        bool res = std::find(cc.begin(), cc.end(), V) != cc.end();

        std::cout << std::boolalpha << res << std::endl;
    }
}
```

- The program output is this

```
internal boost find
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 1 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 2 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 3 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 4 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 5 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 6 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 7 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 8 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 9 found?: false
std::find
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 1 found?: false
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 2 found?: false
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 3 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 4 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 5 found?: false
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 6 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 7 found?: false
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 8 found?: true
row: [9](0,6,0,3,0,0,8,0,4) v: 9 found?: false
```

- as you can see matrix_row.find returns the wrong results
- Does someone know the reason ?

I tried to run different two types of algorithms, one is the internal matrix_row.find and the second is std::find().

- the matrix_row.find returns the wrong results
- the std::find() is correct